# GWT: uiBinder-based widget cant be instanced second time

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I created a widget using GWT uiBinder. It works fine, till the moment when I want to instance it second time. After i call constructor second time it returns only raw description from XML and statements in constructor (`rootElement.add( new HTML( "panel1" ), leftId );`) are just don't work. It throws no error or warning.

Please help

Java class:

```
public class DashboardLayout extends Composite {

final String leftId = "boxLeft";
final String rightId = "boxRight";

interface DashboardLayoutUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, DashboardLayout> {
}

private static DashboardLayoutUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create( DashboardLayoutUiBinder.class );

@UiField
HTMLPanel htmlPanel;

public DashboardLayout() {
    HTMLPanel rootElement = ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi( this );
    this.initWidget( rootElement );

    rootElement.add( new HTML( "panel1" ), leftId );
    rootElement.add( new HTML( "panel2" ), rightId );

}
   }
```

XML descriprion:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             >
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="htmlPanel">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" id="boxLeft" class="boxContextLeft">

                </td>

                <td width="60%" id="boxRight" class="boxContextRight">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing. Your UiBinder widget appears to be correct. How are you adding the widget to a parent widget(RootPanel or a child)?

Comment: Oh, I know what might be your issue. Your id's boxLeft and boxRight are not unique if you add the widget to the DOM a second time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `id="myid"` in widgets, as they will be global(which will screw you up) instead of scoped per instantiation of the widget; use `ui:field="myid"` and then create a corresponding UiField variable in the java class. This will allow the gwt compiler to obfuscate the id's so you don't get collisions between instantiations of the same widget.

DashboardLayout.java

```
public class DashboardLayout extends Composite {

    interface DashboardLayoutUiBinder extends
            UiBinder<HTMLPanel, DashboardLayout> {
    }

    private static DashboardLayoutUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT
            .create(DashboardLayoutUiBinder.class);

    @UiField
    HTMLPanel htmlPanel;

    @UiField
    HTML panel1;

    @UiField
    HTML panel2;

    public DashboardLayout() {
        HTMLPanel rootElement = ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
        this.initWidget(rootElement);

        // do stuff with panel1
        panel1.setHTML("<blink>blink</blink>");

        // do stuff with panel2
        panel2.setHTML("<marquee>marquee</marquee>");
    }
}
```

DashboardLayout.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="htmlPanel">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" class="boxContextLeft">
                    <g:HTML ui:field="panel1"></g:HTML>
                </td>

                <td width="60%" class="boxContextRight">
                    <g:HTML ui:field="panel2"></g:HTML>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```